# Is it a proper implementation strategy pattern? what's better to use enum or define?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The idea is that when we want to create an object of some type, we will only use a robotcreator and enum from the interface. 
the goal is to  decides what type of robot to use internally, based on a parameter supplied by the client at runtime.

what's better enum or define?

InterfaceRobot.h

```
 class InterfaceRobot
    {
   public:
    InterfaceRobot();
    enum RobType { Y=0, C=1, D=2, F=3 };

    virtual void open() = 0;
    virtual void close() = 0;
 };

#endif // INTERFACEROBOT_H
```

RobotCreator.h

```
class RobotCreator :public InterfaceRobot
{
public:
    RobotCreator(InterfaceRobot::RobType _robType);
    void open();
    void close();
    ~RobotCreator();

private:
    InterfaceRobot *Robot; /** pointer to InterfaceRobot**/
};
```

RobotCreator.cpp

```
RobotCreator::RobotCreator(InterfaceRobot::RobType _robType)
{
    switch (_robType)
    {
    case InterfaceRobot::C:
        this->Robot = new c();
    break;
    case InterfaceRobot::Y:
        this->Robot = new y();
    break;
    case InterfaceRobot::D:
         this->Robot = new D();
    break;
    case InterfaceRobot::F:
        this->Robot = new F();
    break;
    }
}

void RobotCreator::open()
{
    this->Robot->open();
}

void RobotCreator::close()
{
     this->Robot->close();
}

RobotCreator::~RobotCreator()
{

}
```

Example of robot Y.h:

```
class Y: public InterfaceRobot
{
public:
   Y();
   // InterfaceRobot interface
public:
   void open();
   void close();
};
```

Example of robot Y.cpp:

```
Y::Y()
{

}

void Y::open()
{
    cout<< "open Y" <<endl;
}

void Y::close()
{
    cout<< "close Y" <<endl;
}
```

use in main:

```
int main()
{

 RobotCreator rob(InterfaceRobot::Y);
 rob.open();
 rob.close();
}
```

Comment: What's the difference of those implementations you have for `c`, `y`, `D` and `F`. It's unclear which particular problem should be solved with your code. Generally a _factory_ is for creating new instances that implement an interface, whereas _strategy_ is to choose a specific algorithm.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  c,y,d,f are different robot  and each one implements the functions in the interface differently.

Comment: All in all it looks like you simply have a flawed and bad design (referring to none of those desgn patterns you mentioned), which violates the [_single reponsibility principle_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Plus some essentially bad practices and simply not working code (using `delete[]` for stuff created with `new`). Generally note that we don't accept any stub or hypothetical code for review here.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded harsh in some way, but it's not a question about _being gentle_, just what the [policies](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of this site are (see the 2nd bullet specifically).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok great. i will read the policies.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so I dont need to delete?

Comment: You use `delete[]` only when you've been using `new[]` before. In general avoid manual memory management at all, prefer using [_smart pointers_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) or [_containers_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: No, the main problem is the stub code you posted. Also changing your question which already has an answer is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your robot creator is not a factory in the traditional sense, because it never returns the robots it creates, or exposes them publicly. Generally, a factory object would do the same job as a class constructor, with the advantage of being a first-class object that can be passed around, stored in a field somewhere, and so on (without resorting to reflection or other "magic," in languages that support that).

This looks more like a strategy pattern, where it decides what type of robot to use internally, based on a parameter supplied by the client at runtime.

It's difficult to propose an alternate solution, because it's not clear exactly what problem this code attempts to solve.

Comment: Thenks , The idia its like what you said :  "where it decides what type of robot to use internally, based on a parameter supplied by the client at runtime."